# how to write data weave code for given input and output

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

I want to reduce or replace this [] with {}

input: `["abcd,"whyf","thsr"]`

output: `{"abcd,"whyf","thsr"}`

Comment: Are the input and output supposed to be JSON? or just strings?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is in JSON it means it is an array. It could be just a string too. The output is not a valid JSON document, because starting with a curly brackets it means it should be an object, but it misses keys for each value.

If for some reason you are intending to just output a string with the square brackets replaced with the curly brackets, then you can transform the input as a string and then use string replaces to change the characters, but be aware that the output is not valid JSON, nor any other supported structured format.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
write(payload,"application/json",{indent:false}) replace /\[/ with("{") replace /]/ with("}")
```

Output (as a string):

```
{"abcd","whyf","thsr"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the output to be string you can also try the following which uses [`joinBy`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-joinby)

```js
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
'{"' ++ (payload joinBy '","') ++ '"}'
```